# pip install is not installing the latest version of mediapipe

Tags: python, pip, mediapipe

I am trying to install the latest version of Mediapipe using the command `pip install mediapipe`.

According to the page https://pypi.org/project/mediapipe/, the latest version is the number 0.8.6.2, but the command is installing me the version 0.8.3.

I have tried to specify the version number using this command `pip install -U mediapipe==0.8.6.2` but then I got this error:

```
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement mediapipe==0.8.6.2 (from versions: 0.7.10, 0.8.0, 0.8.1, 0.8.2, 0.8.3)                                               
ERROR: No matching distribution found for mediapipe==0.8.6.2
```

Not that the latest version number is not listed in the versions available :(

Can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Try updating your python version. also, it may not work if your version is 3.9 or greater than this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to install python 3.7+ and x64 version to install `mediapipe`.
More info [here](https://github.com/google/mediapipe/issues/1325)

Comment: Thanks @MHP.
I am using Python 3.6.8, I need to upgrade it :)

Comment: @lattejiu yes it does, just besure python version is 3.7+ and the x64 version